# Determine correct date format of Google Form response

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-forms

What is the best way to determine the correct date format (dd/mm or mm/dd) of a Google Form response.

When I use the namedValues object:

```
function onFormSubmit(e){
 var namedValues = e.namedValues;
 var date = namedValues['Date']; // Date=[05/06/2018]
 var date = new Date(date);
 Logger.log(date); //Sun May 06 00:00:00 GMT+10:00 2018
}
```

When I use the value from the spreadsheet:

```
function onFormSubmit(e){  
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  var date = sheet.getRange(row,2).getValue();
  Logger.log(date); //Mon Jun 05 00:00:00 GMT+10:00 2018
}
```

I don't know whether I should be, but I am hesitant using the values from the spreadsheet in an onFormSubmit trigger, since I have experienced instability in the past where I think the trigger was running before the data was being posted to the spreadsheet.

I cannot find anything in the Google Forms documentation stating whether a date response is always in a consistent format. If it was always dd/mm/yyyy I could construct the date using the string parts.

**Is there a way to use determine the correct date format from the namedValues object?**

P.S I would rather not use the moment.js library for this one requirement, so keen to understand if its possible without.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Google form will constantly submit the date in the same format, but your sheet might change the appearance of formatting.

Also, there is now a date [format utility](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)) built into Apps script. You can change the date string to the format that you need.

```
 // This formats the date as Greenwich Mean Time in the format
 // year-month-dateThour-minute-second.
 var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
 Logger.log(formattedDate);
```